# Benefits of SR-IOV when most communications are between guest VMs

Tags: vmware-esxi, amazon-web-services, storage-area-network

I am about to buy a new server to run VWware ESXi (Dell T320 w/25GB + RAID10).  It will mainly be running a Linux host running web applications and a Windows file/database server.  I plan to use AWS Storage Gateway to provide their file systems over iSCSI.  Does SR-IOV offer material benefits for such a set up?  The majority of network communications will be between the guest OSs (iSCSI).  External communication will be at most 100mbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VMware and your use-case, probably not. SR-IOV is handy for external networking, but the scenario you describe sounds like using the VMXNET3 virtual adapters and a separate local virtual switch would do the job.

Something like the following, where vSwitch1 is the storage network between virtual machines:

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that SR-IOV is not just for network adapters. [Storage adapters are also an interesting target for SR-IOV](http://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/Accelerating%20Storage%20Perf%20in%20Virt%20Servers.pdf), although the setup depicted by the asker probably would not be able to benefit from this as well.